# Space for every three digits

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I get a simple comma every 3 digits in my result strings?

The code is as follows:

```
float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]]     floatValue];

float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];

float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
float to = convertTo;
float from = convertFrom;

float convertValue = input;
float relative = to / from;
float result = relative * convertValue;

NSString *convertFromName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSString *convertToName = [_convertFrom objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]];



NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %.4f %@",result, convertToName];


resultLabel.text = resultString;

NSString *formelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                          @" %.4f %@=", convertValue, convertFromName];
formelLabel.text = formelString;
```

This code makes a lot of digits, displayed in a block of text, which is not the most practical way to use the data. How can I implement commas in this code?

For example, `1234567` would be `1 234 567` or `1'234'567`.

Comment: [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:someNumberValue];
```

where `someNumberValue` is an NSNumber object with the number.

This will format the number properly for the user's chosen region formatting.

You can control the number of digits after the decimal if you wish. See the docs for `NSNumberFormatter` for more details.

Comment: follow up question.. I managed to get this stuff to work in my code, how can I make it not ignore and kill all decimals after 0 tho? Like, when i have input as '1.9', it calculates and displays just the number 1.

Comment: Like here [link](http://oi49.tinypic.com/35kqzw9.jpg)
You can see that its not as i would like it to be in a converter. I'll guess its some property, but the cheap guy i am im gonna ask my trusty helper rmaddy first<3

Comment: Are you are still doing this: `float input = [inputText.text floatValue];`? That's wrong for converting user entered text into a number. You should parse the user entered string with your NSNumberFormatter. Also make sure you handle invalid numbers or if the user enters letters.

Comment: input is [this code](http://pastebin.com/TQj0ziqG)
I am using float into the NSNumber, take a look and see if thats what you are talking about. :) @rmaddy

Comment: The problem is how you get the 'input' float value (which isn't shown in the code you linked). You can't just call 'floatValue' on the text field's text. You need to parse the text  field's text with an NSNumberFormat.

Comment: Right. Read my last two comments for the cause and solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18435/discussion-between-oscar-apeland-and-rmaddy)